# Can reaching shared storage capacity prevent a VM from starting up in XenServer?

Tags: virtual-machines, nfs, xenserver, shared-storage

I have a VM installed on XenServer; it's drive is on an NFS share, which has just reached capacity--could this prevent the VM from starting up?

Comment: one of many possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This will block the operating system from starting up, as it doesn't have enough room to create the temp files that it needs to generate during boot up. You will have to expand the drive size on the vm.